# Java - objects in an object?

Tags: java, object, scope

Good morning/afternoon/evening,

I'm a Java beginner, but I've been tasked with making a database application. 
In that application, I'd like to create a class that returns other objects when an instance of that class is created:

```
    public LoadStudents(String query){

    File studentsFolder = new File("Data/Students/");
    try{
    switch (query){

    case "all": // additional cases might be added in the future
      //- that's why I am using the class in the first place

        for (final File entry : studentsFolder.listFiles()){
            if(!entry.isDirectory()){
                FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(entry);
                ObjectInputStream object = new ObjectInputStream(in);
                Student[] student = (Student[]) object.readObject();
                object.close();
            }

        }
        break;
    default: 
        final File entry = new File("Data/Students/"+query+".stud");
        FileInputStream in = new FileInputStream(entry);
        ObjectInputStream object = new ObjectInputStream(in);
        Student searched = (Student) object.readObject(); 

    }
    }

    catch(Exception load){
        load.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My question is: Can the student objects can be accessed when I create the LoadStudents object? If so, how?

```
LoadStudents load = new LoadStudents("something");
load.searched.doSomething();
```

maybe?

P.S. I'm sorry if this is a noobish question, but I'd like to know the answer nevertheless.

Comment: Try something, see if it works. Your idea seems good. Also, maybe don't do the loading in the constructor. That way you can just have a return value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the public methods of a class return Objects (any kind of Object) then other classes can use it without restriction.  There are other rules, but that's the primary one to consider when beginning Java programming.

Also, I recommend that you adopt (in the beginning at least) a different style of organizing your solution.

1. Make your class names reflect things.
2. Make your method names on the class reflect what you can do with that thing.

so

```
public class Database {
  .....

  public Student getStudentById(String id) {
    ....
  }

  ....
}
```

which then get used like so

```
Database database = ....

Student bob = database.getStudentById("2323");
```

or something like that.

With this approach, then you could add a "StudentListener" interface, like so

```
public interface StudentListener {
   ....
   public void studentAdded(Details ...);

}
```

And make the database accept student listeners.

```
(in Database)
public void addListener(StudentListener listener) {
   ...
}
```

Then when a student addition is done calling the additional lines

```
for (StudentListener listener : listeners) {
   listener.studentAdded(details);
}
```

will have the listeners be notified by the database that a student was added.

The pattern above is known as the Listener pattern, and you should learn it.  It is very useful in many situations, and you will see it again.

Answer (score 0):

Add Student searched object to class.

ex.

public Student searched;

In constructor set object to searched field. You dont need to create new object.